# Python/Django - radiobutton with submit button instead of buttons

Tags: django, django-forms, radio-button

I have a Django application where I want to have a setting: if the email is sent automatically or manually. What I have works, but not in the style that I want it.

At the moment I have 2 buttons where you can click them and the setting is set to what you want. But what I would want is radio buttons, that are also already checked or unchecked, depending on the setting.

What I have now is:

**model.py**

```
class AutoSendMail(models.Model):
    auto = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    manual = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    send_type = (
        ('manual', 'MANUAL'),
        ('auto', 'AUTO')
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=send_type, default="manual")
```

**forms.py**

```
CHOICES = [('manual', 'MANUAL'),
        ('auto', 'AUTO')]

class SendMailSetting(ModelForm):
    class Meta:

        model = AutoSendMail
        fields = ['auto', 'manual', 'type']
        widgets = {
            "manual": forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "auto": forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'type': forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class AutoSendView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'core/mailbox/autoSendMail.html'
    context_object_name = 'autosend'
    extra_context = {"mailbox_page": "active"}
    form_class = SendMailSetting

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.POST.get('manual'):
            logger.info("Set to: manual email send")
            AutoSendMail.objects.filter(pk=1).update(auto=True,
                                                     manual=False,
                                                     type="manual")
        elif request.POST.get('auto'):
            logger.info("Set to auto email send")
            AutoSendMail.objects.filter(pk=1).update(auto=True,
                                                     manual=False,
                                                     type="auto")

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

**autoSendMail.html**

```
<form class="card" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">Update Mail Settings</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label">Send E-mail</label>
                    <button type="radio" name="manual" value="manual" class="btn btn-primary">Manual</button>
                    <button type="radio" name="auto" value="auto" class="btn btn-primary">Automated</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image: Currently, it looks like this]

And I would like it to look more like this:

[image: Wanted result]

At the moment I'm only using a POST request, and I guess, to inform the user I also need to use a GET request, but I can't get it to work. Also I'm now not using the form, I tried to use it in different ways but I can't get the result I want..

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had created a modelForm but you are not using it here. Anyway for basic method you can try below method

```
<input type="radio" name="update_type" value="manual">Manual</input>
<input type="radio" name="update_type" value="auto">Automated</input>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

views.py

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   update_type = request.POST.get('update_type'):
   if update_type == 'manual':
       "update db with manual to true"
   else:
       "update the db with auto to true"
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much. Yes the forms I created but did not get it to work. But just for showing what I have here, I also posted it in case someone wants to use it in their answer. But this is great, I have tried so many versions that are almost this. And it works! It would be best if I can let the user know what the current setting is (like in my picture example. Would you know how?

Comment: If the user need to know about the current setting then you can pass a context data by filtering to correspoding user and in the input field try <input type="radio" name="update_type" value="manual" {% if contextdatapassedobject.manual.value %}checked {%endif%}>Manual</input>. Same change for auto  also

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much. The only thing I'm still struggling with is that after the user changes the setting and clicks `Update`, the settings are changed, but the screen does not change. So somewhere I'm missing a refresh call for my page.. I posted it here in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71529876/django-python-update-html-after-update-with-radiobutton)