# Django/Python - update html after update with radiobutton

Tags: python, django, django-views, radio-button

I have a Django app with an email box. Users can send the email by hand or let it be done automatically. To change the setting: either manual or automatic, I have creates a view to change the settings. To show the user what the current setting is, I prechecked the radio button. It looks like this:

[image]

My problem is, that when the button "Update" is clicked, it does change the settings, but not the frontend for the user. So the user does not see that it is changed. So the page should be refreshed or something with the new settings, but I don't know how..

This is the code that I have now:

**.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Send Emails:</label>
    <p></p>
    <input type="radio" name="update_type" value="manual" {% if view.manualSetting %}checked {%endif%}>    Manual
    {% if view.manualSetting is 1 %} ( Current setting ) {% else %} {% endif %}</input>
    <p></p>
    <input type="radio" name="update_type" value="auto"  {% if view.autoSetting %}checked {%endif%}>      Automated
    {% if view.autoSetting is 1 %} ( Current setting ) {% else %} {% endif %}</input>
    <p></p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
class AutoSendView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'core/mailbox/autoSendMail.html'
    context_object_name = 'autosend'
    extra_context = {"mailbox_page": "active"}

    model = AutoSendMail.objects.get(id=1)

    autoSetting = int(model.auto == True)
    manualSetting = int(model.manual == True)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        update_type = self.request.POST.get('update_type')

        if update_type == 'manual':
            logger.info("Set to: manual email send")
            AutoSendMail.objects.filter(pk=1).update(auto=True,
                                                     manual=False,
                                                     type="manual")
        elif update_type == 'auto':
            logger.info("Set to auto email send")
            AutoSendMail.objects.filter(pk=1).update(auto=False,
                                                     manual=True,
                                                     type="auto")

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

When a user is now choosing "Automated" and clicks "Update", the screen stays exactly the same as on the picture above, eventhough things have changed.

What I would want is that when the user choosing "Automated" en clicks "Update" the screen changes to:

[image]

Could someone help me :)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)` try `return redirect('/url/')`